# Can Python's garbage collection guarantee the reclaiming of circular referenced objects under all circumstances?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, circular-reference

This question is an extension of a question I asked earlier: [Python Delegate Pattern - How to avoid circular reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613102/python-delegate-pattern-how-to-avoid-circular-reference) After reading the replies, I decided to clarify my question, but was requested to post it separately.

Here goes:

1. A passage in the Python docs (reproduced below) states that garbaged collection is not guaranteed for circular
   referenced objects. A post I found [here](http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2008/07/07/python-destructor-and-garbage-collection-notes/) suggests the same thing. But the replies to my earlier question disagrees. So, have I misunderstood the passage or are there further
   details that I've missed?
2. I suppose using a weak reference, as stated in Alex Martelli's reply to the question [Should I worry about circular references in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428301/should-i-worry-about-circular-references-in-python) would avoid the overhead for garbage collecting circular referenced objects  mentioned in his reply entirely? If so how does it work?

The relevant Python docs that suggests conflicting following passage from Python's doc:

> CPython implementation detail: CPython currently uses a
>   reference-counting scheme with (optional) delayed detection of
>   cyclically linked garbage, which collects most objects as soon as they
>   become unreachable, but is **not guaranteed to collect garbage
>   containing circular references**. See the documentation of the gc module
>   for information on controlling the collection of cyclic garbage. Other
>   implementations act differently and CPython may change. Do not depend
>   on immediate finalization of objects when they become unreachable (ex:
>   always close files).

The passage in its original form can be found here: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html The bold setting is mine.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the most important reason that objects with circular references aren't *guaranteed* to be collected is that, by design, Python *never* collects objects with circular references *if they define a* `__del__` *method*. There is a pretty [straightforward reason](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.garbage):

> Python doesn’t collect such cycles automatically because, in general, it isn’t possible for Python to guess a safe order in which to run the `__del__()` methods.

I am loath to say that this is the *only* reason unreachable objects with circular references might not be detected. There are probably a few unusual situations that could foil the GC's cycle detection mechanisms. But unless you define `__del__` for one of your objects, you're *probably* ok. Just don't worry about it, and use the GC's extensive debugging options if you see performance issues.

Comment: Hi. So from your answer, can I say that circular reference might lead to memory leaks but in general this tend not to be serious. If there is a noticeable performance hit, we should be able to tell from the debugger. Given the benefit of doubt, the replies to my previous post are probably along the same spirit as yours. Further, to avoid the problem entirely, we could use a weak reference to refer one of the object in the cycle to break the circular reference.

Answer (score 1):

When it says it's not guaranteed to collect circular references, that's exactly what it means. Whenever you're data structures contain circular references, the reference count will always be non-zero, meaning that reference-counting alone is not enough to decide when to delete them. On the other hand, finding *all* circular references after reaching the end of each scope would be time consuming--to say the least. It would involve analyzing the relationships of all objects with a non-zero reference count.

That said, I don't expect that you'll have a problem with it, in general. For a light script, you can just ignore it. For others, you still have to do some clean up work at the end of scope (closing a file, or even removing the circular reference), as you would in C, for instance, but it's still not as heady as C.

If it becomes a problem, just remove the circular reference before you finish with each data object.