# Why do circular references prevent the destructors of objects that aren't on the loop?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, destructor

In this example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print "Foo died"

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
        self.baz = Baz(self)

class Baz(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

b = Bar()
```

I'd expect the Foo destructor to be called in spite of the loop between Bar and Baz, as since Foo holds no references to any bar or baz collecting them and decrementing reference counts should be completely safe to do before collecting Foo. Why doesn't python behave this way? How can destructors possibly be useful if they can be prevented from being called by completely unrelated actions of other classes?

Comment: Why would `foo` be deleted if it is referenced?

Comment: Simple answer: destructors are not useful.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2428301/10077

Comment: @LevLevitsky It is no longer referenced once b goes out of scope (i.e. when the program ends). Try this example with the `self.baz` line commented out, you'll see the destructor called.

Comment: @DanielRoseman But they're the only way to safely handle certain cleanup situations... context managers don't work across threads. And as far as I can tell this use case _could_ be safe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the destructor [does not need to be called when the interpreter exits](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__).

A quick modification to your script and all works as you expected:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print "Foo died"

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
        self.baz = Baz(self)

class Baz(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

b = Bar()

del b
```

Comment: Oh! Well now I feel dumb. I assumed it would work the same as when I didn't have the `self.baz` line. Thanks, will mark as accepted when the time limit ends.